# Creating a button in classes. Can someone help why this doesnt work

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *                                        
root = Tk()                                                  
                                                             
def main():                                                  
    Window1 = Window(root, "hello", "500x500",)              
                                                             
class Window:                                                
    def __init__(self, root, title, geometry,):              
        self.root = root                                     
        root.title(title)                                    
        root.geometry(geometry)                              
        root.mainloop()                                      
                                                             
class Button(Window):                                        
    def __init__(self, message):                             
        self.message = message                               
        super().__init__(root,)                              
        Button(root, text=message,).pack()                   
        root.mainloop()                                      
                                                             
Button("HI")                                                 
                                                             
                                                             
main()
```

Comment: have no clue why the init does have the underscores i copy and pasted in

Comment: You need to format it in code blocks. [Edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues.

Firstly, you're creating a subclass of Window called "Button". When you subclass something, it means that it will be of a similar type as it's parent (Window != Button). But more than that, when you define Button, you're actually hiding tkinter's button!

Second, you need to think about the event loop. When working with GUIs, you want to set everything up (where is the button, where are form elements, etc.) before running the mainloop (where possible). You're calling the root.mainloop function in each element, when you should only really call it once (and probably in your main() method).

So how to actually do it? You're code *may* look something like this

```
from tkinter import *


class Window:
    def __init__(self, root, title, geometry, ):
        self.root = root
        root.title(title)
        root.geometry(geometry)

    def add_button(self, label):
        btn = Button(self.root, text=label)
        btn.pack(side='top')


def main():
    root = Tk()
    Window1 = Window(root, "hello", "500x500", )
    Window1.add_button("Hi!")
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here, the window has a method called "add_button", where you can add whatever button you want. Note that it is just creating a new Button object (the parent is "root") and then is "packing" it (feel free to read more about tk's layouts), which puts it in its place

I've also cleaned up the main function and called it under the classic 'if **name** == "**main**":' line.

Answer (score 1):

One of the two major issues I see is that your `Button` class is hiding the one that `tkinter` defines with the same name that would have been available via the `from tkinter import *`. The second one is that your `Button` shouldn't be derived from your `Window` class because subclassing implies there's is an "is a" relationship between the two classes — which is clearly not the case with them.

Below is an object-oriented way to do things that *does* work:

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP 8 recommends avoiding `import *`


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    window1 = Window(root, "hello", "500x500")
    Button(root, "HI")
    root.mainloop()


class Window:
    def __init__(self, root, title, geometry):
        self.root = root
        root.title(title)
        root.geometry(geometry)


class Button:
    def __init__(self, parent, message):
        self.message = message
        tk.Button(parent, text=message).pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: so the parent acts as the root in the class in button

Comment: Yes. When you create widgets in `tkinter` they are always *in* some kind of container, either the root or another `Toplevel` window, or a `Frame` (which is a widget group), and the first argument passed to them when they're created is always their "parent" or "master". I made it a parameter passed to `Button.__init__()` to avoid using a global variable.

Comment: Here's a good explanation of what `parent` is: [tkinter basics](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Introduction_to_GUI_Programming.html#tkinter-basics).

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk                                                                                 
                                                                                                     
def main():                                                                                          
    root = tk.Tk()                                                                                   
    window1 = Window(root, "hello", "500x500")                                                       
    Button(root, "Click me", 2, 2, 10, 5)                                                            
    root.mainloop()                                                                                  
                                                                                                     
                                                                                                     
class Window:                                                                                        
    def __init__(self, root, title, geometry):                                                       
        self.root = root                                                                             
        root.title(title)                                                                            
        root.geometry(geometry)                                                                      
                                                                                                     
                                                                                                     
class Button:                                                                                        
    def __init__(self, parent, message, row, column, width, height,):                                
        self.message = message                                                                       
        self.row = row                                                                               
        self.column = column                                                                         
        self.width = width                                                                           
        self.height = height                                                                         
        tk.Button(parent, text=message, height=height, width=width).grid(column=column, row=row)     
                                                                                                     
                                                                                                     
if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                           
    main()
```

the grid function isnt working now lol

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).